# Why are declarations necessary

Tags: c#, .net, variables, clr, declaration

I am currently teaching a colleague .Net and he asked me a question that stumped me.

Why do we have to declare?

if var is implicit typing, why do we have to even declare?

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
```

becomes

```
var animal = new Animal();
```

could become

```
animal = new Animal();
```

The implicit typing would still mean that this is a statically typed variable.

If two different types are assigned to the variable, if they do not share a base class, (other than object), that could be a compiler error.

Is there a technical reason this could not be done or is it stylistically we like havein

Comment: How would you know if you were wanting to declare a new variable, or use an existing one?

Comment: Type inference was new in C# 3. Before then, `var` didn't exist. Also, even when the type *can* be inferred, it may be *clearer* for you to document the expected type of a complex expression.

Comment: What @starskythehutch is trying to say is, how does the compiler know when you are an idiot who typoed a variable name. Fact is, in languages that do what you suggest, that is probably the most common bug.

Comment: In my opinion it makes code much cleaner, you don't have to wonder if you are using previously declared variable or the new one.

Comment: In short. Its because use statically typed programmers LIKE compiler errors.

Comment: To be able to define the scope for the variable?

Comment: VBA lets you do this.  I challenge you to go write a huge Excel macro like this - abuse the crap out of not having to declare things and see what kind of trouble you get yourself into.  Sometimes learning the hard way is incredibly illuminating.

Comment: @A.Tapper The scope (within a method) could be decided in the same way as it is with declaration - first place it is used is it's scope.

Comment: @starskythehutch & Aron as far as I can see compilers not catching typos is the most legitimate reason, leading to an extra level of static analysis complexity and unit testing.

Comment: Because that's JavaScript.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Of course, that *would* be possible.

I can think of a few reasons you don't want this:

1. What is the scope of your variable? Not clear if you don't tell the compiler. Will `animals` in two methods become a private variable or two method scoped variables?
2. What if the name is a typo? You will never know.
3. What if you already assigned a value to this variable and then try to assign a new value which is incompatible with the last (i.e javascript style) (credits to [Mario Stoilov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1818847/mario-stoilov))

Comment: To clarify, an example of 1. Value is generated by a disposable, but is consumed somewhere else. Without explicit scoping, you couldn't dispose the disposable, and keep the value you assigned in scope at the same time.

Comment: @patrick.  1) a member level variable would be declared at the class level, otherwise normal rules. 2) language protecting us against ourselves, a valid reason 3) this would be a compiler error; If one subscribes that Methods should be small and limited non declared variables to Methods, just like anonymous Types, it should not be a problem (except Typos!)

Comment: @PatrickHofman the typos + anything is possible comment cover what I need to say to my colleague. thanks.

Answer (score 13):

One very important reason is that it helps to prevent errors caused by accidentally mistyping a variable name.

Imagine, you want to reassign string `myString` to have a new value:

```
myString = "New value";
```

But you accidentally type this:

```
myStrimg = "New value";
```

This will cause a compile-time error. However, if you allow implicitly created variables per your question, this will silently create a new variable, with predictably hilarious results...

Answer (score 11):

As suggested by Brad Smith http://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/336 :-

> > There seems to be a tendency for some programmers to use var for every
> >     variable declaration. Sure, the language doesn’t stop you from doing
> >     this and, indeed, MSDN admits that this is a “syntactic convenience”…
> >     But it also warns quite strongly that:
> >
> > the use of var does have at least the potential to make your code more
> >     difficult to understand for other developers. For that reason, the C#
> >     documentation generally uses var only when it is required.
> >
> > Implicitly Typed Local Variables (C# Programming Guide), MSDN
> >
> > I discovered recently that the commonly-used tool ReSharper
> >     practically mandates liberal use of var. Frankly, this isn’t helping
> >     the situation. There are some developers who try to argue the stance
> >     that var somehow improves readability and broader coding practices,
> >     such as this article:
> >
> > By using var, you are forcing yourself to think more about how you
> >     name methods and variables, instead of relying on the type system to
> >     improve readability, something that is more an implementation detail…
> >
> > var improves readability, Hadi Hariri
> >
> > I agree with the premise of the quote above, but not with the end
> >     result. On the contrary, the overuse and misuse of var can lead to
> >     some very bad habits…
> >
> > Let’s look at the argument against the widespread use of var (and for
> >     its sparing, correct use):
> >
> > Implicitly-typed variables lose descriptiveness
>
> The type name provides an extra layer of description in a local variable declaration:

```
 // let's say we have a static method called
 GetContacts() // that returns System.Data.DataTable  
 var individuals = GetContacts(ContactTypes.Individuals); 

 // how is it clear to the reader that I can do this?   
 return individuals.Compute("MAX(Age)", String.Empty);
```

> > My variable name above is perfectly descriptive; it differentiates
> >     between any other variables populated using GetContacts() and indeed
> >     other variables of type DataTable. When I operate on the variable, I
> >     know that it’s the individual contacts that i’m referring to, and that
> >     anything I derive from them will be of that context. However, without
> >     specifying the type name in the declaration, I lose the
> >     descriptiveness it provides…

```
   // a more descriptive declaration   
   DataTable individuals = GetContacts(ContactTypes.Individuals)
```

> > When I come to revisit this body of code, i’ll know not only what the
> >     variable represents conceptually, but also its representation in terms
> >     of structure and usage; something lacking from the previous example.

Extra Notes :-

Here are a couple of good/bad examples based on a reasonable usage of implicit variable declaration…

- Good:

  ```
   var numbers = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};

   var stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();

   var cars = new List();

   var orders = new Dictionary();
  ```

+/- OK with either (but prefer explicit declaration):

```
 int pages = 10;
 string username = “john”;
var username = “john”;
var order = GetOrder(orderId); // ok if the type is Order, otherwise not
 for (var x = 1; x < 10; x++)
```

- Bad:

  ```
     var settings = GetInboxSettings(); // not obvious at all

    var userId = GetUserId(); // ambigous, is this guid, string, int or a custom UserId object?

     Dictionary orders = new Dictionary(); // redundant
  ```

Answer (score 2):

When we declare a variable `xxx`, we indicate the following to our tooling

- make room for an object
- that will live in this scope
- and be of this type (optionnally)

What we say to our humans is

- an object named xxx exists in this scope
- of this type (optionnally)

The scope is essential to both aspects, since the tooling needs to know how long the variable will live, and the humans need to see where a variable lives. The type can be a good information to have, but many languages live without it so I'd argue it is not as important, but YMMV

The compiler can determine what the scope of a variable would be, for example by deciding that the first encounter of a variable name is the declaration of the variable, and any word with the same name below that is a reference to that variable. Humans, on the other hand, cannot keep track of this kind of complexity successfully.

So I would say that we have **one good reason to declare variables: to tell the humans reading our code that it exists**. Declaring variables increase their visibility and clarifies information that is essential to our understanding of the program.

Comment: if we limited this to just methods, with regards to scope, maybe the compiler could just say the first scope it sees it in is the scope it is in.  with regards to visibility, the humans would see it when when it is assigned, with var all declaring a variable is stating to humans is this is the first place / scope in which I use this variable.

Comment: Limiting this to methods then declaring variables is indeed "useless" since the variable wouldn't get out of the method, except as an argument or a return variable. However it slightly complicates for a human the act of detecting where in the method the variable is instantiated. Of course, using small methods render this point moot, but that's another subject :)

Answer (score 1):

There must be many reasons. One of the reason I can think of is ambiguity between property/field reference versus new variable.

However, probably C# compiler team can still develop such a feature. But using var simplified everything. We saved design effort, development effort, testing effort and maintenance effort. Most important, it makes you code more **readable**.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not disputing the facts which are put across here in some answers. Rather I would like to answer differently:

```
int count;
if(someConditionIsTrue)
    count = 3;
else count = 1;
```

I can not use "var count" here. Can I?
Now which one of the following two lines looks pretty :

```
Tuple<int, string, bool, float> tuple = new Tuple<int, string, bool, float>(1, "p", true, 3.0f);
```

OR

```
var tuple = new Tuple<int, string, bool, float>(1, "p", true, 3.0f);
```