# Retrieve AD results to Listbox VisualStudio

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get the results from Active Directory to a listbox I created.

Normally I code in Excel VBA but in this case I needed to move my project to Visual Studio so that I can later compile it to an exe.

So here is my Excel VBA code which is working perfectly:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;"

Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

objCommand.CommandText = _
 "<LDAP://OU=ABC-computers,dc=ABC,dc=local>;(objectCategory=computer);name;subtree"
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

rcArray = objRecordSet.GetRows
 
With UserForm1.ListBox1
    .ColumnCount = 1
    .Clear
    .List = Application.Transpose(rcArray)
    .ListIndex = -1
End With
 
objConnection.Close

End Sub
```

I have started a new Visual Studio project (Visual Basic -> Windows Form Application) and created "Form1". But when I tried to incorporate the above code it didn't work.

Below is the screen:

[image: Error]
<sub>(source: [gulfup.com](http://im54.gulfup.com/Yx9eME.png))</sub>

After trying for hours to adapt it, I couldn't get anywhere close :(

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: "It didn't work" is not enough information, please list the specific error you get on which line.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for the reply, the error is in the fact that the `objConnection` & `objCommand` get underlined with a light blue line as if though they were not recognized. When I run it, it crashes at `Set objConnection`.

Comment: [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30549626/edit) and when it crashes visual studio should be showing you the exact exception you got. [copy those exception details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276.aspx) in to your question. Also with the blue lines if you mouse over them it should tell you what it thinks is wrong.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Many thanks for trying to help. I have edit the question as requested. Hopefully this will make things clear.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you first need to declare the variable before you can use it. [Else it wouldn't know the scope for example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23626245/993547)

In order to declare a variable in VB.NET, you need to use the `Dim` keyword:

```
Dim objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

[Some required reading on declaring variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke6sh835.aspx)